# C# with System.Data.SQLite - closing connections

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm well aware that I should do SELECT query like that:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection scrsql_con = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=db.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
scrsql_con.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select something FROM something";
cmd.Connection = scrsql_con;
SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//reading stuff from datareader...
dr.Close();
scrsql_con.Close();
```

However, there are a lot of SELECT queries in my application, so I decided to make a method for that.
Right now it looks like the following:

```
public static SQLiteDataReader GenericSelect(String query)
{
        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection scrsql_con = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=SCRdb.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
        scrsql_con.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Connection = scrsql_con;
        SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         return dr; 
}
```

But it's not very good, since it leaves scrsql_con hanging.I can't close it from inside of GenericSelect method, because it means that it will always return empty datareader or error, and I can't close it from the outside.
Any suggestions how should I do GenericSelect properly so it keeps returning datareader?

I know I can use datatable, but aside from performance,this method is used in a lot of places, so I will save a lot of time if it keeps returning what he returns now.

Comment: Your GenericSelect method is a `static` so your connection is created and destroyed every time you call that method.

Comment: Why don't you return a DataTable?

Comment: Because he need to change every procedure that calls the GenericSelect? Because filling a DataTable and then looping on that effectively doubles the perfomance hits?

Comment: i would like to think so,but i keep getting "database locked" error when i use it from time to time.So,connection is probably well and alive after i use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first fix is

```
SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

and this according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx)

> When the command is executed, the associated Connection object is
>   closed when the associated DataReader object is closed.

Of course it is now of paramount importance to be sure to call `SQLiteDataReader.Close`.